# MVC different Get and Post to the controller method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Let's get straight..

I need to accept get data and post data to the controller method.
I have an ajax call with some post data parameter (let say id & name) which will target to the landing page like this: /master/data?page=student.

So I have 3 parameter need to be passed:
1. page ==>send with GET method
2. id ==>send with POST method
3. name ==>send with POST method

I have controller method like this but it didn't work out. How fix it?

```
<HttpPost()> _
<HttpGet()> _
Function data(page as string, id as Integer, name as string) As ActionResult
    bla..bla.bla...
End Function
```

Comment: You shouldn't need these http* attributes, but otherwise this should work. What does "didn't work out" mean?

Comment: Oopss..my fault...actually it works. I got a null value and I though because of this. Sorry, it pass the value as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before youre controller

```
<AcceptVerbs("Post", "Get")>
```

AS

```
<AcceptVerbs("Post", "Get")>
<AllowAnonymous()> _
Function data(page as string, id as Integer, name as string) As ActionResult
    bla..bla.bla...
End Function
```

**Otherwise do not put any HTTP verbs to allow all**

Comment: First, sorry that it is my fault. It actually works. I have problem with my ajax script which pass null value. What is the different using <AcceptVerbs("Post", "Get")> and <HttpPost()> and <HttpGet()>? It is still working for me using <HttpPost()> and <HttpGet()>.

Comment: Yes It will but the correct way of allowing the multiple Verbs is passing them in the AcceptVerbs list :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer it a different way personally. IE with example code:

```
 [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult RegisterUser(Register model)
     {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             ViewBag.stuff= new stuffDbContext().stuff;

             // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
             return PartialView("RegisterUser", model);
         }

  [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult RegisterUser()
     {

             return PartialView();
     }
```

It might break the DRY of OO programming however it stands by the MV-WYFY design pattern.